# How to get value of node in firebase database in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.respublished = 
functions.database.ref('/Posts/{postid}').onWrite(event => {
  const snapshot = event.data;
  const postid = event.params.examid;
  const uid = snapshot.child('uid').val();
  const ispublic = snapshot.child('Public').val();
  firebase.database.ref('Users/' + uid).once(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    const name = snapshot.child('name').val();
  });
});
```

The event is triggered by another node and i want to retrive data from another node of firebase database. I have tried the above code but it produces an error saying TypeError: firebase.database.ref(...).once is not a function.

Comment: Are you sure about that exact error message?  Do you mean `firebase.database.ref().once`?  If so, what is `firebase`?  Did you define it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

yes i got the answer we can use this code

```
exports.respublished = functions.database.ref('/Posts/{postid}').onWrite(event => {
  const snapshot = event.data;
  const postid = event.params.examid;
  const uid = snapshot.child('uid').val();
  const ispublic = snapshot.child('Public').val();
  return admin.database().ref('Users/' + uid).once(event => {
    const snapshot = event.data;
    const name = snapshot.child('name').val();
  });
});
```